# why the sql insert not using postgresl 13 auto generate seed

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

Today I encount an wired problem, the insert sql in mybatis did not using the PostgreSQL primary key seed. This is my PostgreSQL 13 primary key id auto increment seed value:

```
select CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('rss_sub_source', 'id'))
```

the current value is 1233. but when I insert a new record in mybatis in my app, it get a id less thatn 1233 cause some trouble. this is the log I am traced from my app:

```
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3ba3aecd]
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - Creating a new SqlSession
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@374a5a38] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1612904926 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4adde074] will not be managed by Spring
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO rss_sub_source (sub_url, created_time, updated_time, rss_type, standard_version, next_trigger_time, sub_name, fav_icon_url, local_icon_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - ==> Parameters: https://redbus2us.com/feed/(String), 1621658832422(Long), 1621658832422(Long), RSS(String), rss_2.0(String), 2021-05-22 12:47:11.677(Timestamp), RedBus2US(String), https://redbus2us.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/redbus2us_simple_logo.png(String), 2021/5/22/redbus2us.com-redbus2us_simple_logo.png(String)
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@374a5a38]
2021-05-22 12:47:12.479 ERROR 20238 --- [io-11014-exec-1] c.d.s.p.c.i.channel.SubSourceController  : rss parse error

org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rss_sub_source_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(334) already exists.
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis/mapper/dolphin/RssSubSourceMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.dolphin.soa.post.dao.RssSubSourceMapper.insertSelective-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO rss_sub_source (sub_url, created_time, updated_time, rss_type, standard_version, next_trigger_time, sub_name, fav_icon_url, local_icon_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rss_sub_source_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(334) already exists.
; ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rss_sub_source_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(334) already exists.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rss_sub_source_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(334) already exists.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:247) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:88) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:271) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.insertSelective(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.channel.SubSourceService.insert(SubSourceService.java:215) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.channel.SubSourceController.rssParse(SubSourceController.java:180) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.channel.SubSourceController.subChannel(SubSourceController.java:126) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.channel.SubSourceController.pluginAdd(SubSourceController.java:164) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.channel.SubSourceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$967c088.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.channel.SubSourceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$60ae071c.pluginAdd(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor376.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141) ~[spring-session-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rss_sub_source_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(334) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:59) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:47) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor451.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.invokeUpdate(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:93) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.intercept(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:55) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.invokeUpdate(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:93) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.intercept(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:55) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DynamicDataSourceInterceptor.intercept(DynamicDataSourceInterceptor.java:68) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:184) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor448.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

2021-05-22 12:47:12.480  WARN 20238 --- [io-11014-exec-1] m.s.advice.ControllerResponseAdvice      : (SERVICE EXCEPTION - SC: 200, RC: 00100100064009) -> 无法解析RSS地址
^C
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz dolphin-post]#
```

seems the logic is, the mybatis app send a insert command to PostgreSQL, then PostgreSQL using the auto generate primary key id as an id to execute insert action. but get the id is less than seed, the database aleay has this id and did not able to insert.

why get a seed unrelated id when insert? what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Seems to me that the internal sequence is "out of sequence". Did you add/restore data to the table without using the sequence, serial or identity column? This can probably resolved by resetting the sequence in the schema.

Comment: I found this table id has two sequence. @TheImpaler